# C# Get Date From Computer

Tags: c#, date

I'm trying to get the date into a string in C#. I want the format of:

> 2011.02.14

Which is, YYYY.MM.DD

Can someone please let me know the command for this? And also is there a way to do like Date(-1)?

Thanks.

Comment: What's the variable type in the first place? DateTime? String?

Comment: try @abmv then declare a string like : string a;

Comment: "I'm trying to get the date into a string in C#".  What date?  There are lots of dates.  Do you mean the *current* date?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

- System.DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy.MM.dd");
- System.DateTime.Now.AddDays(-1)

Answer (score 1):

For the first:

```
string s = DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy.MM.dd");
```

For the second, you'd need to be explicit about what `Date(-1)` should return, but I expect it involves `var foo = someDate.Add(timespan);` or `var foo = someDate.Add{SomeInterval}(delta);`

Answer (score 1):

Declare a string like :

```
string mydate;

myDate = DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy.MM.dd");

messagebox.show(myDate);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do that using DateTIMe's ToString method, more info [on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zdtaw1bw.aspx)